# BASE SAS Regular Expressions: Performing String Extractions on Several Variables at Once

Tags: arrays, regex, sas

I have some SAS code that applies a Regular Expression to a URL string which pulls out a Category ID.

The Variable looks like this:

**URL**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=61765546&cp=1766205&ab=en_US_MLP_SLOT_1_S1_SHOP

http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/index.jsp?categoryId=62593996&AB=en_US_HP_S2_Men_slot_1_S2_ShopNow
```

I apply this code:

```
data Want;
set have;
category_Id=input(prxchange('s/.+categoryId=(\d+).+/$1/o',-1,URL), 12.);run;
```

I get this:

```
category_Id
61765546
62593996
```

The dataset I have actually has many URL variables – **URL_1**, **URL_2**, **URL_3**….. and so on.  It could go up to 80 URL vars or it could be 10.

What I need to do is pull the category IDs out of all the URL vars and then transpose them by Campaign_Name.

The data looks like this.

```
Campaign_Name   URL_1   URL_2   URL_3   URL_4
Summer Campaign http://www.mywebsite.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=61765546   http://www.mywebsite.com/shop/index.jsp?categoryId=62593996&AB=en_US_HP_S2_Men_slot_1_S2_ShopNow    http://www.mywebsite.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=62593846&cp=1766205&ab=ln_men_cs_thetrend:tropicalprints   http://www.mywebsite.com/family/index.jsp?categoryId=62594006&cp=1766205
```

My final output needs to look like this:

```
 Campaign_Name  category_Id
Summer Campaign 61765546
Summer Campaign 62593996
Summer Campaign 62593846
Summer Campaign 62594006
```

I assume you would use an array but I'm not sure how to program that.

Comment: I'm interpreting this as not a regex question but only an array-transpose question, which the linked duplicate gives you a couple of solutions for.  Apply the regular expression after you've transposed the initial URLs, or apply it during the transpose if that's easier if you use the data step method.

Comment: I don't know Array syntax very well.  After looking at the exampl, I'm not sure how to modify it.                                                 data want;
 set have;
 array vars URL : ;
 do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
  category_Id=input(prxchange('s/.+categoryId=(\d+).+/$1/o',-1,_i), 12.);
  output;
 end;
run;

Comment: Not `_i` as the argument but `URL[_i]`.